# Generate anonymous listener in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, actionlistener, anonymous-class

Is there any way to automatically generate appropriate listener in NetBeans?

For example, when I have JButton, and I type **button.addActionListener**, I'd like NetBeans to generate following code:

```
new ActionListener()
{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NetBeans ***is capable*** of pregenerating listeners, ***without*** using Code Templates.

It is possible by typing **new SomeListener** and pressing CTRL+Space.

[image]

And viola!

[image]

Comment: This is what I use and it's working surprisingly well. If I were to choose than this would be my accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

To create event-listeners with NetBeans, open the file with your button, get to the "Design"-tab and select your button. In the sidebar on the right you should see the properties of the button. If not, be sure the properties-panel is activated under Window -> Properties. If you got the properties, select the "Events"-tab, and the first event you should see is the actionPerformed-event. In the dropdown-list you can either use the default event-name, or give it your own. If you selected it, NetBeans automatically creates the code you posted above for you.

Comment: I'm not using NetBeans GUI builder.

Comment: Then Vincents answer could be a help to you!

Answer (score 2):

You need a code template for this. **Tools>Options>Editor>Code Templates**

[image: Code Templates]

You can then click **New** and add your own abreviation say 2act. Then when you type:

```
 button.2act
```

and hit tab, Netbeans will replace 2act with your code.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aaware of that, but I'm looking for something more automatic (e.g. not necessarily ActionListener)

Answer (score 0):

You want to create your own new Template for this, so go into the `Tools` menu then the `Templates` submenu to reach the `Template Manager`. Then click on the `Java` folder and you can see a listing of  the pre-existing Templates. To see what's in them, click on edit. To copy one, highlight the template and click duplicate. For more on how to create and modify templates search on `Template Manager` in the NetBeans help files.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can insert a template file in your current file.  However, "Code Template" is a completely different beast and more useful: it defines abbreviations that NetBeans expand when you press tab.  For example you could define an abbreviation such that "al[tab]" would expand to the exact actionListener code above and it can even place the cursor between the braces.  See Tools > Options > Editor > Code Template.

Comment: toto: Yeah, Code Templates is a real beast, I have yet to master it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Miscelleneous -> GUI Builder.

You''ll find some options as to how your listeners are generated.

[image: GUI Builder]

Comment: Not for me, as I manually create GUI. See my answer for correct way of doing this.